# How to unit test a forced unwrapping

Tags: swift, xctest, swift2

In Swift with XCTest, is it possible to test the result of a forced unwrapping?  I'm hoping for something like Jasmine's `expect(...).toThrow()`:

```
let a: Something? = MAYBE_NIL_MAYBE_NOT

func unwrap()
{
    a!
}

XCTAssertCausesError(unwrap)
```

Comment: `XCTAssert(a == nil)`

Comment: Let me revise the question :)

Comment: If you want to ensure that value-a should not be nil, you can use `XCTAssertNotNil`. If you want to ensure that it is nil, you can use `XCTAssertNil`

Comment: @iosDev82 In this case, the question is about catching the error that results from a forced unwrapping which fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the new `XCTUnwrap` to unwrap an object and assert if the value is nil.

```
let optional: String? = "optional"
let unwrapped: String = try XCTUnwrap(optional) // throws
```

in a non-throwing function, you can use `guard` for a test-failing one-liner like so:

```
guard let unwrapped = try? XCTUnwrap(optional) else { return }
```

This is essentially the same as testing a force unwrap. Just use the function rather than `!`.

> `XCTUnwrap` asserts that an Optional variable’s value is not nil, returning its value if the assertion succeeds.
>
> This removes the need to combine `XCTAssertNotNil(_:_:file:line:)` with either unwrapping the value or dealing with conditional chaining for the rest of the test. For example:

```
func testFirstNameNotEmpty() throws {
    let forenames: [String] = customer.forenames

    let firstName =  try XCTUnwrap(forenames.first)
    XCTAssertFalse(firstName.isEmpty)
}
```

Announced at WWDC 2019 and in the Xcode 11 release notes:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes

Comment: Thanks @pkamb, this looks perfect and I've changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

By definition in swift you can't catch a forced unwrap failure. Also, I don't think using forced unwrap in production code is a good idea, unless you are absolutely certain that will not fail.

You can get an unwrapping exception if you use:

```
 guard let a = a else { throw ... }
```

instead of `a!`

Comment: Nice explanation about why using forced unwrap is not a good idea. But if it could be tested, then we could be (reasonably) sure that it wouldn't happen, with less verbosity than guard will introduce.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer but [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) on forced unwrapped values says the following:

> NOTE
>   Trying to use ! to access a non-existent optional value triggers a runtime error. Always make sure that an optional contains a non-nil value before using ! to force-unwrap its value.

The swift language (2.0) doesn't currently have syntax to trap these `runtime error`s.  These are likely equivalent to segmentation faults/kills which don't get trapped by Objective-C's `@try/@catch` syntax.

It also appears that you're testing the language's functionality itself, (i.e. that force-unwrapping a `nil` value will throw an exception) and not your app's logic.  You're better off catching a `throw` as suggested by @Mario Zannone.

```
let a: Something? = MAYBE_NIL_MAYBE_NOT

func unwrap(test: Any?)
{
    guard let value = test else {
        throw // an ErrorType
    }
}

XCTAssertCausesError(unwrap(a))
```

Comment: Good explanation. This is fine except for computed variables being unable to use throw (and hence guard) yet, so testable code will have to use getter functions for now.  Thanks.